# Fast way to determine order of two line segments which intersect with a vertical line

Tags: algorithm

Is there a better way to determine order of two line segments which intersect with a vertical line? the order is according to the y-coordinates of the points of intersection.
The naive approach is to caculate the intersection points and compare.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  What do you mean by order? Drawing a picture is often a good way to show things, and perhaps give an example of a situation and the answer you would expect to be returned by the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some pointers to solve this problem:

- A more faster way to find the intersection between lines can be with the use of determinants as show this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection).
- An algorithm to solve the more general version this problem, is the [Bentley–Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm), created for testing whether or not a set of line segments has any crossings.

I believe this entry in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection) about Line segment intersection encompasses your inquiries in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the lines are specified using endpoints.

The intersection of a line with endpoints (`x0`, `y0`)/(`x1`, `y1`) and a vertical line with x coordinate `x` is at:

```
y = (dy/dx)(x - x0) + y0
```

where `dx = x1 - x0` and `dy = y1 - y0`.

You have 2 lines and are calculating:

```
(day/dax)(x - ax0) + ay0 < (dby/dbx)(x - bx0) + by0
```

You can multiply both sides by `dax * dbx` to get rid of the divides:

```
(day * dbx)(x - ax0) + (ay0 * dax * dbx) < (dby * dax)(x - bx0) + (by0 * dax * dbx)
```

and simplify a bit:

```
(day * dbx)(x - ax0) - (dby * dax)(x - bx0) + (ay0 - by0)(dax * dbx) < 0
```

This isn't necessarily better -- it depends on the situation:

- If the coordinates are integers, this allows you to perform the test exactly, but it's also prone to overflow if `dax`/`dbx`/etc are large
- If the coordinates are floats, it may be faster if floating point divide is slow